# php date format help

Tags: php, date

I am having a little trouble with changing the format of a date with php, the format in question is dd/mm/yy, however I wanting to change that to yyyy-mm-dd.

I have tried doing this,

`date('Y-m-d', '23/04/10')`

Answer (score -1):

The second argument for [`date()`](http://php.net/date) should be unixtimestamp and not a string like you have. Use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) (you might need to change the string, read up on the manual!) to convert your string to unixtimestamp first.

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('23/04/10'))
```

Comment: You didn't test this, that format is not parsed by `strtotime`.